# Video display problem from Laravel - Vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js, video, vuejs2, html5-video

I am developing a website using Laravel and Vuejs. I am trying to show a video on a page. I am trying to get the video using Laravel and show the video using Vuejs but the video is not appearing or maybe I am wrong all the time while reading the video or while receiving the video.

#### Code from Laravel method from where I am getting the video file from:

```php
$data = Usercvvideos::select('id','userid','name','cv_video','upload_file_type')->where('userid', $id)->where('upload_file_type', $request->gettingFileType)->get();

$source_file = public_path()."/".$data[0]->cv_video;
$filesize = (string)(filesize($source_file));
$fileName = explode("/".$data[0]->userid."/", $data[0]->cv_video);
$originalFileName = $fileName[1];
        
header('Content-Type: video/mp4');
header('Content-Length: ' . $filesize);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $originalFileName . '"');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

readfile($source_file);
```

Here `$data[0]->cv_video` is the path, as example: `uploads/100/abcd.mp4`.

#### Code from Vuejs function from where I will receive the video and will show it on the video/source tag:

```js
async getIntroData(){
    var gettingFileTypeByString={
        'gettingFileType': 'introVideo'
    };

    let returnValue;
    try{
        await axios.put('url', gettingFileTypeByString).then((response) => {
            returnValue = response.data;
        });
    } catch(e){
        console.log(e);
    }

    this.axiosGetIntroVideo = returnValue;
}
```

I also tried to return `returnValue` from the function, also called the function from video src:

```js
let buffer = returnValue;
let videoBlob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(buffer)], { type: 'video/mp4' });
let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(videoBlob);
this.axiosGetIntroVideo = url;
```

Video tag is something like:

```
<video>
    <source :src="axiosGetIntroVideo">
</video>
```

I also tried it this way:

```
<video>
    <source :src="getIntroData()">
</video>
```

But I failed all the times. When I received something from `getIntroData()` function, I tried to see what I am getting in the response. I am adding a screenshot below:

[image]

Please, help me to get the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Why not skip all the Vue and Laravel?

```
let url = "uploads/100/abcd.mp4";
this.axiosGetIntroVideo = url;
```

and let the browser and HTML do all the lifting for you?

Comment: i tried this way, it needs another `"/"` for it..something like `src="/uploads/100/abcd.mp4"` ..
but it does not allow me to set `currentTime`..please help me..i don't know why it is not allowing me to set `currentTime`..is it because of i am using vue component? there must be way. please help me if you find any way

Comment: where do you need currentTime?  That is not part of your question.

Comment: i did not mention about `currentTime` here because i think i am not even getting the actual video or maybe the process is wrong or maybe i need to receive the video in a different way to use `currentTime`..if i get the actual video then `currentTime` will definitely work i believe.. that is why i did not mention about `currentTime` here in my question

Comment: you asked for help in getting the video t play. IDK what you are trying to do with currentTime, as you have not provided any code or explanation.

Comment: i am sorry. if i don't get the video properly then currentTime cannot be set. i asked for currentTime because if someone clicks in the video progress bar currentTime need to be called. first i need the video properly, if i get the video properly then i will be able to work with currentTime

Comment: here is another question i asked recently. i hope i could explain my problem here properly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67891156/video-receiving-problem-from-laravel-to-vuejs

Comment: to add the progress bar to the video add the "controls" attribute the the video tag: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video

Comment: i added controls. the problem is when i click on the video progress bar, suppose the video started playing, and i clicked on the video progress bar at 25 sec, from where i want to watch the video. the click operation don't work on video progress bar. when i click on the video progress bar, video again starts from zero second