# Video receiving problem from Laravel to Vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js, video, vuejs2, html5-video

- I stored the video link in the database and stored the video in the `public folder`. a folder description is something like `public/uploads/100/abcd.mp4`.
- I am reading this video from a Laravel method and receiving this video from Vuejs and trying to show the video in the `<video>` tag. I also tried to show the video using the direct link, something like `<source src="/uploads/100/abcd.mp4">`.
- But this way I can only show the video but the video progress bar is not working and currentTime cannot be set this way because I tried to set it.
- Maybe I need to receive the video in Vuejs using a different way. Please give me a solution to this. I am adding the Laravel method and Vuejs method here, which way i tried to receive the video, I don't know if it is the correct way to receive the video. Please give me the solution if you have any.

**the video-tag**

````
```
    <video>
       <source v-bind:src="axiosGetIntroVideo">
    </video>
```
````

- Laravel method from where I am getting the video path and reading the video and returning the video.

```
    $data = Usercvvideos::select('id','userid','name','cv_video','upload_file_type')->where('userid', $id)->where('upload_file_type', $request->gettingFileType)->get();
    
    $source_file = public_path()."/".$data[0]->cv_video;
    $filesize = (string)(filesize($source_file));
    $fileName = explode("/".$data[0]->userid."/", $data[0]->cv_video);
    $originalFileName = $fileName[1];
    
    header('Content-Type: video/mp4');
    header('Content-Length: ' . $filesize);
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $originalFileName . '"');
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
    
    return readfile($source_file);
```

- Vuejs method from where I called the Laravel method written here and trying to receive the video and trying to show the video in `<video>` tag

  ```
  async getIntroData(){
          var gettingFileTypeByString={
              'gettingFileType': 'introVideo'
          };
          let returnValue;
          try{
              await axios.put('url' + this.userId, gettingFileTypeByString
                  ,{
                  responseType: "arraybuffer",
                  headers: {
                      "Accept": "video/mp4",
                      },
                  }
                  ).then((response) => {

                  console.log(response);
                  returnValue = response.data;
              });

              let buffer = returnValue;
              let videoBlob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(buffer)], { type: 'video/mp4' });
              // let videoBlob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(buffer)]);
              let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(videoBlob);
              this.axiosGetIntroVideo = url;
          }
          catch(e){
              console.log(e);
          }
      }
  ```
- This way in Vuejs I tried to get the video but it is not working. please help me to get the video. I am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You should just record to db url where you uploaded file. Then just set that string to src of video. Also you'll need control attribute in video tag.

Comment: but this way currentTime cannot be set and video progress bar don't work this way. it works only in raw html file. but i am using vue component. direct link or string don't work in vue component. i tried this way

Comment: @anonymus Strinng don't work? Then how blob which is string works? You messed up your upload/symlink to public folder. 

As for current time, you can always use percentages. Determine how much is, for example 1s, is in percents.